# Scala / Play Framework - how to batch GMail API requests

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, gmail-api

I'm using Play Framework to implement an application, in which I'm using GMail REST API. To optimize for network, I would like to perform [batch requests as per GMail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch). I wonder, is this possible to implement using [Play Framework WS API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS) or would I need to use a lower-level API? If not, which Scala API I could use to implement it?

Comment: i would say it is not possible, at least easily. you probably can set the content-type and do some work to put the batch in the same request..have you tried to ask on the play-framework google group?